# Why is Mathematica Giving Such an Incorrect Answer for These Integrals? Huge Error Estimate

Tags: numerical-integration

I'm trying to evaluate two integrals using Mathematica and it gives a huge error estimate, seemingly due to its highly oscillatory nature. I know that the absolute value of both integrals is less than $16\pi^5$ (which is less than 5000). Both functions are perfectly smooth and bounded so the issue can't be coming from that. Here is a screenshot of the issue: https://ibb.co/tq112Rb. On top is the first function I want to integrate, and on the bottom is the code and the value Mathematica outputs. For the first integral I am inputting:

```
NIntegrate[Exp[10I*(Sin[a]+(Sin[b]+x*Sin[b]-
 y*Cos[b])/(Sqrt[1+x^2+y^2])+Sqrt[2]*(Sin[c]-
 Sin[d])/(Sqrt[1+x^2+y^2])-Sqrt[2]Sin[c+d]*(1-x^2-
 y^2)/(1+x^2+y^2))]/(1+x^2+y^2)^2,{x,-1000,1000},
 {y,-1000,1000},{a,0,2Pi},{b,0,2Pi},{c,0,2Pi},{d,0,2Pi}]
```

I know that the absolute values of the integrals should be less than $16\pi^5$ because of the triangle inequality and the fact that

$\displaystyle \int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\frac{1}{(1+x^2+y^2)^2}\,dx\,dy=\pi\,.$

Is there a way I can approximate these integrals? In the same vein, are the error estimates reliable? That is, if the error estimate Mathematica gives is 100, is it true that the true value is within 100 of the estimated value?

Comment: Multi-dimensional integrals are difficult to do numerically. Try to go as far as you can with analytic integration: here, for example, you can do all the angular integrals analytically (they are Bessel-style integrals).

Comment: I think that you can do the integral over `a` analytically.   That would simplify it slightly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In what follows I will assume that your integrations over $x$ and $y$ can be extended to infinity. With this assumption, we switch to [polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) $(r,\phi)$ defining
$$
x=r\cos(b+\phi),\qquad y=r\sin(b+\phi).
$$
The integral becomes
$$
\int_0^\infty dr
\int_0^{2\pi} d\phi\, da\, db\, dc\, dd
\frac{r}{(1+r^2)^2}
e^{10i\sin a}
e^{\frac{10i}{\sqrt{1+r^2}}\sin b}
e^{-\frac{10ir}{\sqrt{1+r^2}}\sin \phi}
e^{10\sqrt{2}i\left(\frac{\sin c-\sin d}{\sqrt{1+r^2}}\right)+\frac{r^2-1}{r^2+1}\sin(c+d)}
$$
Several of the angular integrals are now separable: we have
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} e^{i u\sin a}da=2\pi J_0(u)
$$
in terms of the [Bessel function of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel_functions_of_the_first_kind). Only the $c$ and $d$ integrations are coupled in a non-trivial way. For the $c$-$d$-integration we define the auxiliary integration function
$$
g(u,v)=\int_0^{2\pi}e^{i (u (\sin c-\sin d)+v \sin (c+d))}dc\,dd
=2\pi\int_0^{2\pi}\,J_0\left(\sqrt{u^2+v^2+2 u v \cos d}\right)\cos (u \sin d)dd
$$
Putting all of this together, the integral becomes manageable:

```
g[u_?NumericQ, v_?NumericQ] :=
  2π*NIntegrate[BesselJ[0, Sqrt[u^2 + v^2 + 2 u v Cos[d]]] Cos[u Sin[d]],
                {d, 0, 2π}]

NIntegrate[(2π*BesselJ[0, 10]) *
           (2π*BesselJ[0, 10/Sqrt[1 + r^2]]) *
           (2π*BesselJ[0, (10 r)/Sqrt[1 + r^2]]) *
           g[10*Sqrt[2]/Sqrt[1 + r^2], 10*Sqrt[2]*(r^2-1)/(1+r^2)] *
           r/(1+r^2)^2, {r, 0, ∞}]
(*    -0.818883    *)
```

As a single integral, where you can play with the `Method` and `WorkingPrecision` options more easily,

```
(2π)^4 * BesselJ[0, 10] *
NIntegrate[r/(1 + r^2)^2 *
  BesselJ[0, 10/Sqrt[1 + r^2]] *
  BesselJ[0, (10 r)/Sqrt[1 + r^2]] *
  BesselJ[0, 10 Sqrt[(2 (2 - r^2 + r^4))/(1 + r^2)^2 + (4 (-1 + r^2) Cos[d])/(1 + r^2)^(3/2)]] *
  Cos[(10 Sqrt[2] Sin[d])/Sqrt[1 + r^2]],
  {r, 0, ∞}, {d, 0, 2 π}]
(*    -0.818883    *)
```

Comment: This is very interesting and will probably help me in the future, thank you! I wonder what the reason is behind this working, as you seem to simply be using the definition of the Bessel function.

Answer (score 6):

> I know that the absolute value of both integrals is less than 16*Pi^5
> (which is less than 5000)

Too large for comment:

Mathematica is having hard time with numerical integration for this. I have no solution other than to point that using `Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 5000}` gives values less than 5000, but this depends on what number one uses for `MaxErrorIncreases`. I found that different values gives different result.

May be someone will find an option that is better. But here is what I found for whatever it is worth

```
integrand = 
 Exp[10 I*(Sin[
       a] + (Sin[b] + x*Sin[b] - y*Cos[b])/(Sqrt[1 + x^2 + y^2]) + 
      Sqrt[2]*(Sin[c] - Sin[d])/(Sqrt[1 + x^2 + y^2]) - 
      Sqrt[2] Sin[c + d]*(1 - x^2 - y^2)/(1 + x^2 + y^2))]/(1 + x^2 + 
     y^2)^2;

res = NIntegrate[
   integrand, {x, -1000, 1000}, {y, -1000, 1000}, {a, 0, 2 Pi}, {b, 0,
     2 Pi}, {c, 0, 2 Pi}, {d, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 5000}];
Abs[res]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But using `Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 8000}` now gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So clearly this option makes big difference. So I do not trust these result from `NIntegrate`

I tried also Maple on this, but Maple could not even give an answer (numerical integration). This seems hard integrand even for numerical integration.

Comment: So you cannot even estimate the lower bond? We know the upper bond... With 9000 you get 1.62916. And 10000 gives 1.61029.

Comment: Wow thank you so much for doing this, I really appreciate it! Though it's too bad it's so difficult..